# Given two lines find the four circles that have the lines as tangents

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Given two lines, each defined by two points, and a radius find the four circles that have the lines as tangents. I give my attempt below but there ought to be a nice mathematica way of doing this.

```
ClearAll[tangetsAndCircles];
tangetsAndCircles[{p1_, p2_}, {p3_, p4_}, r_] := 
 Module[{L1, L2, intersection, λ1, λ2, s1, 
   s2, θ1, θ2, d1, d2, q1, q2, q3, q4},
  L1 = p1 + λ1 (p2 - p1);
  L2 = p3 + λ2 (p4 - p3);
  intersection = 
   L1 /. First@NSolve[L1 == L2, {λ1, λ2}];
  s1 = Normalize[p2 - intersection] ;
  s2 = Normalize[p4 - intersection ];
  θ1 = 1/2 ArcCos[s1.s2];
  d1 = r/Sin[θ1];
  θ2 = 1/2 ArcCos[-s1.s2];
  d2 = r/Sin[θ2];
  q1 = intersection + d1 (s1 + s2)/Norm[s1 + s2];
  q2 = intersection - d1 (s1 + s2)/Norm[s1 + s2];
  q3 = intersection + d2 (-s1 + s2)/Norm[-s1 + s2];
  q4 = intersection - d2 (-s1 + s2)/Norm[-s1 + s2];
  {intersection, q1, q2, q3, q4}

  ]
```

Here is an example

```
{p1, p2, p3, p4} = 
{{0.1246, 0.1491}, {0.0501, -0.8392}, 
 {0.6457, 0.7347}, {-0.4134, -0.2812}};
r = 0.2;

{p, q1, q2, q3, q4} = tangetsAndCircles[{p1, p2}, {p3, p4}, r];

Graphics[{PointSize[0.02], Purple, Point[{p1, p2, p3, p4}], Black, 
  InfiniteLine[{p1, p2}], InfiniteLine[{p3, p4}], Red, Point[p],
  Lighter@Blue, Circle[q1, r], Circle[q2, r], Circle[q3, r], 
  Circle[q4, r]}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Can you suggest a simpler and more robust method? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
p = First[RegionIntersection[InfiniteLine[{p1, p2}], InfiniteLine[{p3, p4}]]]
dir1 = r Normalize[Normalize[p4 - p3] + Normalize[p2 - p1]];
dir2 = Cross[dir1];
q1 = p + Csc[VectorAngle[p4 - p3, p2 - p1]/2] dir1;
q2 = p - Csc[VectorAngle[p4 - p3, p2 - p1]/2] dir1;
q3 = p + Csc[VectorAngle[p4 - p3, p1 - p2]/2] dir2;
q4 = p - Csc[VectorAngle[p4 - p3, p1 - p2]/2] dir2;
```

The use of `Csc` is like computing the green length below where the orange and blue segments correspond to your lines:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, nice use of `RegionIntersection` .  `VectorAngle`  is also one to get to know.